# How can we return instance of class from ladon functions in python?

Tags: ladon

I want to return a instance of user defined class and list of instances of user defined class from a ladon function? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

this might help  you its something like this

```
from ladon.ladonizer import ladonize
from ladon.types.ladontype import LadonType

class Response(LadonType):
    values = [int]

class MyService(object):
    @ladonize(int, int, rtype=Response)
    def foo(self, a, b):
        result = Response()
        result.values = [a+b, a*b]
        return result
```

Comment: Suppose from my program 'PG1', we are calling a ladonize function. From the ladonize function it will call a function in another module, for eg: Module1. From 'Module1', it returns one instance of class A and list of another instances of class B. Both A and B are user defined. Then from the ladonized function, I want to return both instances into my program 'PG1'.